# Office Online Server and Provider Hosted Apps on the same server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365, sharepoint-apps, provider-hosted

I am trying to work on Provider Hosted Apps for few functionalities here and at the same time configuring Office Web App Server. As per the documentation at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219435.aspx#software it says

> You can use physical servers or virtual machine instances, but you can’t install other server applications (such as SharePoint 2013 or SQL Server) on the same server as Office Web Apps Server.

Does it mean it should exclusively be used only for office web app server or can I use the same server to host my provider hosted app's web site.

Thanks
DNN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but you can’t install other server applications (such as SharePoint 2013 or SQL Server) on the same server as Office Web Apps Server.

Let's know more about that with software requirements for Office Web Apps :

1. Office Web Apps Server/s must be independent from other applications and services such as SharePoint, Exchange, Lync, Skype4B. Do not deploy Office Web Apps on a server that runs any of the above applications and that is not supported.
2. Don’t install any services or applications that depend on IIS 80, 443 or 809 Ports because OWA frequently removes web applications on these ports in order to bring up the OWA Web applications.
3. Do not install any Office client applications on OWA Servers as it is not recommended.
4. Do not install OWA on a Domain Controller or any Domain Server runs critical services such as DNS or AD DS.

So ,in order to overcome potential conflicts such as port conflicts,i would suggest you to keep the office web app server independent with other application and server include your provider-hosted app web application/service/database.

Comment: Yeah, It made sense to have its own server. I read somewhere that Office Web App Server frequently rebuild IIS metabase and its removing all the IIS web sites irrespective of its Office Web App site or any other site.

Comment: [Compatibility with other workloads and services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN#compatibility-with-other-workloads-and-services)